# How can I edit a Raspbian SD card image to use a static IP address within Windows?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, windows

Before "burning" the Raspbian.img file to a SD card, I would like to edit it so the Pi uses a static IP address. (So I can run it in headless mode, without DHCP). I found [some](http://fieldappseng.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/headless-raspberry-pi/) [articles](http://shallowsky.com/blog/hardware/raspberry-pi-without-monitor.html) describing edits I could do in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

> In file `$SDCARD_ROOT/etc/network/interfaces`, find line:
>
> ```
> iface eth0 inet dhcp
> ```
>
> and change it to something like:
>
> ```
> iface eth0 inet static
> address 192.168.1.145
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> gateway 192.168.1.1
> ```
>
> (obviously, these are example IP addresses, replace them according to your
>   needs).

But how can I do the edits in the image file when I'm on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(might also be possible with ["Raspberry Pi emulation for Windows" project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/files/no%20image/) instead of Levinux, but below is how I did it before I found out about the former)

The following steps seemed to work for me:

1. Download [Raspbian ISO](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest) ([torrent](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest.torrent))

   - see also [raspberrypi.org/downloads](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) for more info on tools required for writing onto SD card
2. Download [Levinux](http://mikelev.in/ux/) (~20MB), unzip into `Levinux` folder.
3. Add raspbian img file as new virtual disk in Levinux:

   - go to `Levinux\Levinux on Mac.app\Contents\MacOS\`;
   - copy `RunOnWindows.bat` to new file `RunWithRaspbian.bat` in the same directory;
   - right-click `RunWithRaspbian.bat` and choose `Edit` (to open in Notepad);
   - below line with:
     `-hdc tce.qcow ^`
     add a line like:
     `-hdd 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img ^`;
   - move the Raspbian .img file `2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img` to the same folder where your edited .bat file exists;
4. Start Levinux: double-click `RunWithRaspbian.bat`;

   - if it crashes when doing some installation stuff, try starting again (worked OK for me on next start);
   - Login: user: "tc", password: "foo"  ([source: tinyapps.org](http://tinyapps.org/blog/nix/201305250700_levinux.html));
   - `sudo su` ;
   - `mount /dev/sdd2` # (mount partition 2 of raspbian img);
   - `cd /mnt/sdd2`;

Now, after typing `ls` you should see contents of your SD-card. You can edit files with `vi`. *(NOTE: `vi` is a very user-unfriendly text editor, unfortunately; you must google for some tutorials how to edit anything in it, sorry! The most important is to know how to exit from vi without saving: `ESC ESC ESC :wq!`.)*
**UPDATE:** if Internet connection will work for you from Levinux console, you can try installing the "nano" editor, which is more user-friendly than "vi"; the following steps should make it work:

```
tce-load -wo nano.tcz
tce-run nano
# or just:
nano
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the existing answer. I use a simpler solution to assign static IP **for eth0** in `Raspbian (Jessie)` from Windows.

**Assuming you want to use use `255.255.255.0` as subnet mask**

Open your SD card installed with Raspbian with Windows Explorer through card reader. You'd find cmdline.txt. Open `cmdline.txt`and add `ip = x.x.x.x` after `rootwait` (x.x.x.x being the intended IP address).

Save it (with admin rights if needed)

It's ready to use.

Comment: what do you mean by `cmdline.txt`?

Comment: Open your SD card installed with Raspbian with Windows Explorer through card reader. You'd find cmdline.txt. I used this method to give IP address to RPi's eth0.

Comment: @WidiWidiyanto This is very interesting thanks.  This seems to set my eth0 ip address to the value I give it but what about wlan0?  Is there a way to update that instead?  Or both?  I am using wifi and it still uses dhcp for wlan0 with your solution.

Comment: @Eradicatore If I remember correctly, I edited eth0 first, then I use P2P connection & SSH to my RPi. Or just VNC into it. Then I configure wlan0 from there. A bit too simplistic, but hey it worked. LoL

Comment: @WidiWidiyanto ok, thanks.  I was hoping for a simple way to setup a static ip for wlan0 as well as eth0 but from your reply and from other research sounds like that's not "simple".  Thanks for the reply!!!

Comment: @WidiWidiyanto One correction on this by the way:  netmask does NOT have to be 255.255.255.0.  See the help at http://kr15h.github.io/RPi-Setup/index.html#titles.3. You can use something like ip=192.168.1.200::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off
 at the end of cmdline.txt to set the other parts of your connection.  I just confirmed netmask with this just now.  Not sure yet what the "off" at the end is for yet.

Comment: @Eradicatore yes, it does not have to be 255.255.255.0. I just used that to simplify my answer. I mean, that was simply what I needed at that time. Thank you for sharing your research. 

Answer (score 4):

After you have written a fresh Raspbian image to your SD card, mount the SD card. If it isn't visible in File Explorer, just remove the card from the slot and reinsert it after 10 seconds or so.

Open the SD card, then find and open the file `cmdline.txt` in Notepad. Save a copy of it, name it something like `cmdline-original.txt`.

It will look something like this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh
```

Change it to this (assuming your IP will be 192.168.1.145 as in your example):

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh ip=192.168.1.145
```

If you've already booted the Raspberry Pi off of this SD card once, you may not have the section `init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh` but just put your `ip=192.168.1.145` bit on the end of the line anyway. It should still have only the one line. Don't let it break across multiple lines.

This is not the preferred way of setting your IP, and the use of `/etc/network/interfaces` has been depreciated in favor of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, so after you succeed in connecting to the Pi you need to open the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and put your IP address in it. If you don't feel comfortable using console-based text editors yet, you can use the following command in your console to insert the IP address info you specified:

```
sudo tee -a << EOF /etc/dhcpcd.conf > /dev/null
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.145/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
EOF
```

This is an expanded version of Widi Widiyanto's answer. I am not able to comment directly, so I posted it like this. Also, don't forget to restore your `cmdline.txt` file to it's original state.